# Como acessar uma DB em uma intancia AWS EC2, utilizando DataGrip ou PgAdmin localmente

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, amazon-aws

Tenho uma instancia na AWS EC2 que possui uma Database no Postgres (Não está na Amazon RDS).
Eu gostaria de acessá-la utilizando alguma ferramenta como o DataGrip ou PgAdmin no meu computador local.

É possível? Como fazer?

Localmente eu consigo utilizar o Datagrip e o PgAdmin para acessar as tables locais, porém na instancia EC2 fico sem saber quais dados de acesso utilizar.

Answer (score -1):

A instance tem IP Publico? Se sim, precisa garantir que sua ACL/SecGroup libere o acesso na porta 5432 (ou a que está configurada para o Postgres).
Porém, cuidado para não expor para qualquer origem.